# Correct use of Syntax in if statement using && Operator and 2 variables

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax, operator-keyword

I have a quick question regarding proper use of syntax, basically i am trying to summarise these two if statements into one if statement.

```
if (sc.LastCallToFunction) {
    if (p_LowRectanglesList != NULL) {
        free(p_LowRectanglesList);
        sc.PersistVars->i1 = 0;
    }
    if (p_HighRectanglesList != NULL) {
        free(p_HighRectanglesList);
        sc.PersistVars->i2 = 0;
    }
    return;
```

Would it be syntactically correct to rewrite this as:

```
if (sc.LastCallToFunction) {
    if (p_LowRectanglesList || p_HighrectangleList != NULL) {
        free(p_LowRectanglesList && p_HighRectanglesList);
        sc.PersistVars->i1 && sc.PersistVars->i2 = 0;
    }
    return;
```

Or would the compiler not accept this / Is my Logic faulty?

Comment: Your logic is very faulty.

Comment: You should almost never call free() in C++. You should very rarely use delete. Look up "RAII" - it will make everything better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do it the way you have given

```
if (p_LowRectanglesList || p_HighrectangleList != NULL)
```

this logically ORs the first pointer ( treats it as true or false ) with the comparison of the seond pointer to NULL

```
free(p_LowRectanglesList && p_HighRectanglesList);
```

this logically &&s the pointers together and then tries to free the result of that operation.  ie, you are trying to free "true" or "false"

```
sc.PersistVars->i1 && sc.PersistVars->i2 = 0;
```

this logically ands the two things together, which will result in true or false and then trys to assign 0 to it..... doesn't make any sense at all.

Also, in your original code....after the free, you should put `p_LowRectanglesList=NULL;`

Comment: I see, so what if i rewrite it as:

if ((p_LowRectanglesList != NULL)|| (p_HighRectanglesList != NULL)) 
Would this be a legitimate syntax solution to my problem?

Comment: thats correct syntax for the if statement, however it doesn't help you...  you still need to independently check each pointer, and free each pointer separately.   that if statement just tells you  at least 1 of those 2 pointers is not null.   Thats not much use.  you need to check each pointer to see its not null, if its not null, free it.

Comment: This is the problem though, in C# if i use the & it checks both and if i use && it will stop checking if the first one fulfills that condition.

I am really struggeling with finding the appropriate syntax for c++ in this case. To be fair for the purposes of my program this syntax should be more than sufficient because if one of the pointers is not null the rest will run.
Its not that i really need to combine the two statements i posted, its just that i am looking for more elegant ways to code this and i am stuck on syntax. Any suggestions because i cant find anything on cplusplus.com

Comment: well you have a couple of options, first option is do it the C++ way.  Which as someone said in the comments on your question is RAII,  and use something like a scoped or shared ptr/unique ptr ( depending if you have boost or C++0x.  The other way is more the C way of doing things which is what you have at the moment, and you could make a function that checks a pointer for being NULL and freeing it if it isnt, then setting it to NULL after freeing it.

Comment: Okay, well i will read up on RAII tommorow, but I have to say its annoying me to no end on how easily this would be implementable in C# vs c++ where i need to worry about garbage collection...

It seems at this point that it is simply easier to just let the syntax stand as i have it in my original code, i wanted to "compress" the code and thus make it more elegant, but it seems like that is not an option without sacrificing some functionality.

Thanks for the help/suggestions, i have checked your answer as the accepted answer.

Its a shame though =/